# creating a new column from an existent categorical column in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data frame like this:

```
ID    col
 1    a
 2    b
 3    c
 4    d
```

I want to create a new column so that if it is a or c, new column will give Y, otherwise N.

So, it will look like the following:

```
ID   col   col1
 1    a    Y
 2    b    N
 3    c    Y
 4    d    N
```

I am working in python3.

Comment: Do you have it formatted as a dictionary or list? For example `{1:'a',2:'b',3:'c',4:'d'}`

Comment: No. it is a data frame

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, simple effective

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4], 
                    'Col':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}) 

df['Col_2'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'Y' if (row.Col=='a' or row.Col=='c') else 'N' , axis = 1)
```